# Does laravel cache all query results?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Does laravel/eloquent remember previous query results or is there a performance impact it I access related models multiple times instead of putting the values into a variable:

```
$user = User::find(1);
doSomething($user->relation->id)
doSomethingElse($user->relation->id)
```

vs

```
$user = User::find(1);
$relatedModelId = $user->relation->id
doSomething($relatedModelId)
doSomethingElse($relatedModelId)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using just one object with a relation, there is no need to change the code.

But if you're loading a collection of objects with a relationship, you need to use eager loading to avoid N+1 problem.

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not actually loaded until you first access the property. However, Eloquent can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model. Eager loading alleviates the N + 1 query problem.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

So, use `with()` method to preload all related data:

```
$users = User::with('relation')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent caches relationships so you don't need to assign relationship to variable as you showed. Keep in mind to use valid case of relationship - otherwise each time you will get new query executed for example:

```
$user = User::find(1);
doSomething($user->relation->id);
doSomethingElse($user->relation->id);
```

only single query will be executed for relation but

```
$user = User::find(1);
doSomething($user->relation->id);
doSomethingElse($user->RELATION->id);
```

2 queries might be executed for this relation